# Restore Screenshot default in OS X Leopard

Tags: macos, screenshot

I tried to change the the default location of the Screenshot function. Now the OS won't capture anything at all because it can't write to the folder. I've changed the permissions on the individual folders and restarted several times. No luck. Does anyone have any idea how to restore the default setting so at least I can get the functionality back?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest fix would be to run:

```
defaults delete com.apple.screencapture location
```

If that fails to work try deleting the actual preference file found at `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.screencapture.plist`

Comment: The first solution didnt work but the second one did. thank you very much!